# How do I remove this field validation error?

Tags: visualforce

We are updating the Force.com page we use for performance reviews with new fields. I created all the fields in my SF org, and updated the VF and Apex code so that they only reflect the new fields we want people to complete. However, I keep getting the "Oops!. . " validation referenced on line 71. It seems to be looking for a value in a field that is no longer on the page, but I can't figure out where. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<apex:page applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" cache="false" docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="PerformanceReviewRemoteController">
<html lang="en">

<head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"     />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.PRsite,'favicon.png')}"/>
        <title>Divurgent Team Member Annual Self-Assessment</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submit() {
                if(!validateForm()) return false;
                var payload={};
                payload.type='self';
                payload.data=grabFormData();
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.PerformanceReviewRemoteController.submit}',
                    JSON.stringify(payload),
                    function(result, event) {
                        console.log(event);
                        window.location.replace('{!URLFOR($Page.PR_submittalThankYou)}');
                    }, {
                        escape: true
                    });
            }

            function validateEmail(email) {
               var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
            }

            function isBlank(str) {
                return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
            }


            function validateForm(){
                var allFieldsGood=true;
                var flds=["#empFirstName","#empLastName","#empEmail","#selfPeriod","#excellence","#learning","#innovation","#trust","#enthusiasm","#genAssess","#achieve","#growth","#measure"];
                var firstBadFld;

                for (var i = 0, len = flds.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (isBlank($(flds[i]).val())){
                        $(flds[i]).addClass("is-invalid");
                        allFieldsGood=false;
                        if(!firstBadFld)firstBadFld=flds[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(flds[i]).removeClass("is-invalid");
                        $(flds[i]).addClass("is-valid");
                    }

                }

                if (!validateEmail($("#empEmail").val())){
                    allFieldsGood=false;
                    $("#empEmail").addClass("is-invalid");
                    if(!firstBadFld)firstBadFld="#empEmail";
                }


                if(!allFieldsGood){
                    alert('Oops!  Please fill out the required fields.');
                    $(firstBadFld).focus();
                }
                return allFieldsGood;

            }

            //grabs data from the input elements and creates JSON string for sending to SFDC
            function grabFormData(){
                var ret={};

                ret.empFirstName=$("#empFirstName").val();
                ret.empLastName=$("#empLastName").val();
                ret.empEmail=$("#empEmail").val();
                ret.selfPeriod=$("#selfPeriod").val();
                ret.excellence=$("#excellence").val();
                ret.learning=$("#learning").val();
                ret.innovation=$("#innovation").val();
                ret.trust=$("#trust").val();
                ret.enthusiasm=$("#enthusiasm").val();
                ret.genAssess=$("#genAssess").val();
                ret.achieve=$("#achieve").val();
                ret.growth=$("#growth").val();
                ret.measure=$("#measure").val();

                return ret;
            }

        </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="outermost" class="container" style="max-width: 800px;">
        <div class="mx-auto d-block sticky-top" style="background-color: white;">
            <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.PRsite,'logo.png')}" styleClass="mx-auto d-block sticky-top"/>
        </div>


        <h1 class="text-center">Divurgent Team Member
            <br/>Annual Self-Assessment</h1>
        <hr/>
        <h2 class="text-center">How to Submit Your Self-Assessment</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>Enter your basic information.</li>
            <li>Provide your answers and click the submit button at the bottom of the screen.</li>
            <strong>
                <li>Click the verification link that will be sent to the email address you provided in step 1.</li>
            </strong>
        </ol>

        <hr/>

        <form class="">
            <h2 class="text-center">Your Information</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empFirstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empFirstName" placeholder="Your First Name" maxlength="50"/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                      Please enter your first name.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empLastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empLastName" placeholder="Your Last Name" maxlength="50"/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your last name.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empEmail">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="empEmail" placeholder="Your Email Address" maxlength="50"/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your valid email address.</div>
                    <small id="clientEmailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">On submittal of this form, you will receive an email with verification link.</small>
                </div>

                <h2 class="text-center">Self-Assessment</h2>
                <h3>Period</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="selfPeriod">Assessment Period</label>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="selfPeriod">
                        <option value=" " selected="true">Choose...</option>
                        <option value="July 1, 2017-June 30, 2018">July 1, 2017-June 30, 2018</option>
                        <option value="July 1, 2018-June 30, 2019">July 1, 2018-June 30, 2019</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Choose a value</div>
                </div>
                <h3><strong>Excellence</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="excellence">Delivers and strives for excellence in all that is said and done. Is solution oriented, 
                        possesses extensive job knowledge, brings value, goes above and beyond standard job goals, and accomplishes 
                        tasks in a resourceful manner. </label>
                    <textarea id="excellence" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Example of how excellence was achieved or demonstrated"></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3><strong>Learning</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Learning">Fosters a learning environment for self, team members, and for clients. Applies lessons learned, job knowledge to teach
                        others, and seeks opportunities to expand knowledge across functions and or tasks.</label>
                    <textarea id="learning" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Example of how learning was achieved or demonstrated"></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3><strong>Innovation</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Innovation">Creative and forward thinking in approaches to leadership, problem solving and project delivery by generating new 
                        ideas, supporting change and implementing innovative solutions.</label>
                    <textarea id="innovation" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Example of how larning was achieved or demonstrated"></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3><strong>Trust</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Trust">Establish and build trust with team members and client through honest communication, ethical behavior and professionalism in 
                        all interactions. Is reliable, meet’s commitments, works independently, accepts accountability, handles change, sets personal standards, 
                        stays focused under pressure, meets attendance/punctuality requirements.</label>
                    <textarea id="Trust" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Example of how learning was achieved or demonstrated"></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3><strong>Enthusiasm</strong></h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Enthusiasm">Enthusiastic about work and Divurgent. Finds joy in what they’re doing. Goes about with an upbeat and positive 
                        attitude, and is inspiring to others.</label>
                    <textarea id="enthusiasm" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Exmaple of how enthusiasm was achieved or demonstrated"></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3>General Assessment</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="genAssess">Share details of your efforts to working effectively with Divurgent, department, practice and/or client.  Share key 
                        accomplishments, projects and outcomes.</label>
                    <textarea id="genAssess" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your comments here."></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>

                <h3>Goals</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="achieve">1) What do you want to achieve within the new performance period? Please be specific.</label>
                    <textarea id="achieve" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your comments here."></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="growth">2) Educational/Career growth plan/initiatives</label>
                    <textarea id="growth" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your comments here."></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="measure">3) How and when will you measure success? Please include end date projection.</label>
                    <textarea id="measure" maxlength="32768" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your comments here."></textarea>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide some text.</div>
                </div>


        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="submit();return false;" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>








        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is in the JavaScript function `validateForm()`. You need to alter this function to match your current form design. It has a hard-coded list of fields it expects to be populated, by HTML id:

```
var flds=["#empFirstName","#empLastName","#empEmail","#selfPeriod","#excellence","#learning",
"#innovation","#trust","#enthusiasm","#genAssess","#achieve","#growth","#measure"];
```

If this does not match your current validation needs or the other Visualforce changes you've made, you'll have to fix it. I see at least one value (`#trust`) that doesn't match the page, where you have `id="Trust"`.

Comment: +1 I just reached the same conclusion... wish I'd seen this before bothering to debug it!